# Where can I learn about CScript?

Tags: arrays, variables, documentation, wsh

I have this piece of code:

```
var arrayParamaters = sParameters["split"]("|");
```

I want to find a documentation that map the functions/variables of a cs script var.
as in the example I treat the **sParameters** as an array, and I would like to know the functions I can use with it...

Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like JavaScript/JScript with square bracket notation. There're many JavaScript references on the Internet; see this questions for some links: [Where is the official JavaScript documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4105784/113116)

There're also [JavaScript IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/665810/113116) that provide syntax completion for built-in JavaScript objects as well as major libraries.

And by the way, `sParameters` in your example is actually a [`string`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) (which is being splitted into substrings), and `arrayParamaters` is an [`array`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp).

Comment: also I've learned the best way to learn is by trial and error... which did me good!